# Leaflet GeoCSV Marker not visible on map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, csv, html

I am trying to load data for a Marker from a csv file and I am using the [GeoCSV plugin](https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV) for that.

I downloaded the js file and added it to my code and also created a csv file in Excel which looks like this:

[image]

The resulting csv file:

```
lat;lng;title
52;8;test
8;52;test2
;;
;;
;;
;;
;;
```

But the two markers dont appear on the map.
I think this is because of how I try to load in and add the data.
I tried using the default example from github and also experimented with the linked examples from github.

My current code:

```
 (function() {                                                                             
 'use strict';            
  var map = L.map('mapContainer');   
  $.get('test.csv', function(csvContents) {
  var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {firstLineTitles: true, fieldSeparator: ','});
  map.addLayer(geoLayer);
  });
  });
```

Comment: Change option `fieldSeparator: ','` to `fieldSeparator: ';'`.

Comment: Nope, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache? Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: Yes, just cleared the cache and nothing changed. Also no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code that prevent display of markers.

First problem is that delimiter in your CSV file is `;`, not `,`, so your separator defining option should be `fieldSeparator: ';'`.

Second problem is that in your code you define function but never execute it, since there is `()` missing at the end to execute it.

Code should then look like this (tested):

```
(function() {                                                                             
  'use strict';            
  $.get('data/test-csv.txt', function(csvContents) {
    var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {firstLineTitles: true, fieldSeparator: ';'});
    map.addLayer(geoLayer);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now my access to the file is being blocked by CORS policy :( . Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Answer above is solution for the problem from your question. It's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem from question was resolved. If you have another problem/question, please post it as a separate question.